# How to tell in MS Project 2010 VBA if the user has deleted a value?

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm working in MS Project 2010, using VBA to read values from the project. In some cases, the project manager has deleted a value from the application by pressing the `del` key on the keyboard. When this happens, the value appears to be empty / null when you look at the screen, however reading the value directly in VBA still shows the original value, for example with:

```
activeproject.Tasks(439).finish
```

This contradiction is leading to frustration in the team. I don't really need it to stop doing this, I just need a way to detect when the value has been deleted. Is there any way in VBA to determine if the user has deleted the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not that a value has been deleted but is still available using vba, it's that the task in question has a [Task Mode set to Manually Scheduled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.manual) and what is displayed in the Finish field is actually the [Finish Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.finishtext) data. All tasks ***always*** have an underlying finish date (and start date), but in Manually Scheduled mode, the Finish Text can be blank in which case the date defaults to the value calculated based on project start, predecessors, duration, etc.

Consider changing the tasks to be Auto-Scheduled and let Microsoft Project do what it's designed to do--schedule. Here's a [quick explanation](https://skillforge.com/auto-vs-manual-scheduling-project/) of manual vs auto schedule.

Comment: That's it exactly. This was the only task in the schedule which was manually scheduled.